# Is it ok to shoot plants with a green screen for chroma key?

Tags: photo-editing, chroma-key, color-green, background-removal

I need to go outside and take pictures of specific plants in one area, then remove the background, resulting in a just-white background. Right now I only have a GREEN screen (for chroma key). Considering that plants often have green elements (leaves), there could be problems. But it is a pretty different  green tone. I want to make it easy for designer to remove background. Will I cause problems by using a green background instead of a blue one?

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible there is enough difference in the plants and the background to pull the subject off the image to drop onto another one relatively well. It might involve how the subject is lit for the shot instead of the specific colour.

"Green" screen is a generic term now. The original screens for traveling mattes were more blue. The characteristic colour was chosen because it was the colour least likely to appear in the matted image. Care was taken to avoid using the "key" so the matte would not have holes that showed through.

You can use most any colour instead of the "green." Ensure that whatever colour you choose does not appear in both the matte and the key when they are used together. Make sure the background has a consistent luminance and hue or you will get irregular edges and holes where there is chroma overlap. Some work may be needed to repair some parts of the image.